# Use "external" GetHashCode and Equals for Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I would like to use a class as key in a Dictionary which does not override Equals nor GetHashCode. It's a class from an external library which I don't want to modify.

So I am wondering if I can use custom "GetHashCode"/"Equals" implemantiotns just for one Dictionary? I was wondering if something like with C++ std::maps was possible

```
template < class Key,                      // map::key_type
           class T,                        // map::mapped_type
           class Compare = less<T>,        // map::key_compare
           class Alloc = allocator<T> >    // map::allocator_type
           > class map;
```

where Compare can be used to define custom comparison.

I don't want to derive from the class because the objects are created outside using the existing class.

I could create a class which contains the original class, but that changes the access to the Dictionary.

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: When you create a `Dictionary` you can pass in an `IEqualityComparer<>` for your keys: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx

Comment: You could write a simple wrapper class for the key which implements the required behaviour, and pass the wrapped keys to the dictionary instead.

Comment: Why do anything at all? Any class is suitable as a key.

Comment: @MatthewWatson No, it doesn't change it, it just tells the `Dictionary` to ignore the `GetHashCode` implementation of the actual object and to use the methods you supply in the interface.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Your right it doesn't let you modify `GetHashCode` but it lets you customize how you compare two keys, so you probably wouldn't use `GetHashCode` at all, but some other public member of the class.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I deleted my erroneous comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure - you can implement [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) and pass that into [the `Dictionary<,>` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx). That's precisely the purpose of that constructor :)

For example:

```
public FooByNameEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
{
    public int GetHashCode(Foo foo)
    {
        return foo.Name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        return x.Name == y.Name;
    }
}

...

Dictionary<Foo, int> map = new Dictionary<Foo, int>(new FooByNameComparer());
```

Comment: In all these years I have failed to notice the GetHashCode(object) method in IEqualityComparer! (I must have just thought it was the normal Object.GetHashCode() method!)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a custom `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` to the constructor of the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`. The equality comparer must implement `Equal` and `GetHashCode`.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<MyKey,MyValue>(new MyKeyEqualityComparer());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Dictionary Constructor (Int32, IEqualityComparer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132074.aspx),

```
public Dictionary(
    int capacity,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer
)
```

where

`comparer` is:

> implementation to use when comparing **keys**

In practise

- you define a type that implements that interface
- pass it to this ctor , so the method of *that* class are useed for equality identification of the keys of the dictionary.

Seems what you want.